# PHP : Make other functions access the $conn variable inside my database connection function

Tags: php

**Make other functions access the $conn variable inside my database connection function**

So here I am absolutely desperate trying to make something work. I know what im trying to do is not OOP neither 100% best practice. It is not for a live website, I am just learning some basic PHP concepts on XAMPP.

**What I am trying to do** is to make the $conn variable inside my database connection function accessible to all other functions that need it. I am thinking of passing it as a parameter, **but how can this be done**? I prefer not using PHP's "global" or $GLOBALS. My method of working right now is with mysqli using procedural methods.

For example I have something like this:

```
function db () {
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
}

function someFunction () {
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
}
```

I never found the answer to my issue...most solutions which I recently got familiar with are OOP based or use somewhat questionable methods.

*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

**SOLUTION A - I would rather avoid not having my connection in a wrapper and using global variables:**

```
global $conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
global $conn;

function someFunction () {
global $conn;
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
}
```

**SOLUTION B - I am not ready for OOP yet but I know this works. The point is I want to learn something different:**

```
class Database
{
    private static $conn;

    public static function getObject()
    {
        if (!self::$conn)
            self::$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");

        return self::$conn;
    }
}

function someFunction () {
$result = mysqli_query (Database::$conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
}
```

**SOLUTION C - Not using functions at all...just keeping it unwrapped which I dont find very practical in the long term:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");

$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
```

*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

**THE SOLUTION I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**

```
function db () {
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
return $conn;
}

function someFunction () {
$conn = db ();
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
}
```

**OR Something like this where I just pass in the connection as a parameter or something (pseudo code at the moment)**

```
function db () {
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
}

function someFunction ($conn) {
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples)
}
```

*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

**So how do I achieve something like the last two but which actually works. Is this concept possible?**

Comment: OOP isn't really about picking the most obtuse approach. Use the one that's the least effort and API complexity for *your actual use* case. Overplanning for issues you don't actually have or just for some best practice meme isn't that advisable.

Comment: you are already showing a solution here _"THE SOLUTION I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:"_ ; why will this not work for you?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Your Desired Solution:** This should work, and you'll only make one connection.

```
function db () {
    static $conn;
    if ($conn===NULL){ 
        $conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    }
    return $conn;
}

function someFunction () {
    $conn = db();
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples);
}
```

If you used the `function someFunction($conn)`, that would make your code much messier, since you wouldn't actually have universal access to `$conn` from anywhere.

You should go with **Solution B** IMO. That way, you can have simple access to it `Database::$conn` which will be consistent throughout your script. You <strike>could</strike> should have an `initialize` function (you could use a different name if you want) that will initialize `Database::$conn`, and you can then use that to initialize other things on the `Database` class later, if desired.

**Solution A** is terrible. I did that for a long time (`global`izing things), and it was a horrible idea. I should have never done that. But I did. And I learned. It just made code get progressively sloppier and sloppier.

**Solution B:** `Database::$conn` should be `public` if you want to be able to access it by `Database::$conn` from anywhere. If it's private, then you would always need to call `Database::getObject();`

**Solution C:** You're right. That would be very impractical.

**Solution B rewrite:**

```
class Database
{
    /** TRUE if static variables have been initialized. FALSE otherwise
    */
    private static $init = FALSE;
    /** The mysqli connection object
    */
    public static $conn;
    /** initializes the static class variables. Only runs initialization once.
    * does not return anything.
    */
    public static function initialize()
    {
        if (self::$init===TRUE)return;
        self::$init = TRUE;
        self::$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    }
}
```

Then... call `Database::initialize()` at least once before it gets used.

```
<?php
Database::initialize();
$result = mysqli_query (Database::$conn, "SELECT * FROM examples);
?>
```

**EDIT**

- You can also call `Database::initialize()` immediately after the declaration of the class, in that PHP file. Then initializing is handled.
- I'm now far more fond of something like `Database::getDb()` than accessing the `$conn` property directly. Then `initialize` can be called from the `getDb()` function. Basically like the **Desired Solution** but inside a class. The class really isn't necessary, but it can be nice if you like classes, like I do.

Comment: $Jakar by the way, what does the static conn do?

Comment: so that the value doesnt get lost outside?

Comment: When I declare `static $conn`, it makes it so there is only one instance of `$conn` that exists within that function... So `$conn` will refer to the static one (which persists through multiple function calls) rather than a local (local to the function) variable. Without `static $conn`, then every time you call `db()`, `$conn` would be undefined/NULL until you assigned it.

Comment: Also, if you use **Solution B**, then you can also use an autoloader to automatically call initialize. I have an example on my site at http://forum.jakar.co/php-static-class-initializer-using-autoloading/538034/

Comment: interesting. Im using the desired solution one but will 100% use the OOP singleton (I think thats what you call it) which you showed me when im going over to OOP

Comment: you missing " after query string "SELECT * FROM examples **"** Thanks

Comment: @Jakar can you write db disconnect method as you connect in `db` method?

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers in this section are overkill as they are doing overhead just by creating a wrapper around a database object.
For separation of concern(Maintainability) use a separate PHP file for database connection and use require_once.

//Inside Database_Connect.php

$db = mysqi_connect(localhost, database, password);

Now use $GLOBALS['db'] inside your mysqli_ functions wherever needed.

OR, initialize your script / object as

$dbConn = $GLOBALS['db'];

and use $dbConn inside your mysqli_ functions wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer just pass your `$conn` variable into another calling function(instead of making new connection)

like

**yourpage.php**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
someFunction ($conn)//you can add other parameters if you like 

function someFunction ($conn) {
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples);
}
```

Note:This is not good practice to always make new connection for database access.so always make connection once and use it every where.(but if your requirement different and require multiples connections then you can make multiples connections)

Answer (score -1):

Pass an argument to your function like and return the connection

```
function db($conn){
   $conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
   return $conn;
}
```

Comment: .. and return it from the `db` function: `return mysqli_connect(...)`

Comment: Why are you passing `$conn` and then setting `$conn`? I think you're on the right track but the example function, as written, is useless

Comment: how does this answer the OP's question?

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple php files which require db access, then the option you can have is create a file connection.php with connection code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "database");
?>
```

And use     `include_once 'connection.php';`     in all other files you require a connection.

Comment: That's not what OP asked.