# db connection not establish for function

Tags: php, mysql

I have dbconnect.php file to use all my php files eg., index.php etc.. Also i have functions.php file having all the functions. I always getting nothing when i call a function.

`setparentid_new($studentid)` is a function located in "/functions/functions.php" which path already included in index.php.
all the functions is not working because of db connection is not there. If i include dbconnect.php in all the functions then only return the results.

`$parentid` is hanging, so below all code not executing.

`$con` not available in functions. In all functions `$con` need to decalre.
Please help to pass `$con` value to each functions globally.

**dbconnect.php:**

```
<?php 

define("mysqli_HOST","localhost"); 
define("mysqli_USER","root"); 
define("mysqli_PASSWORD",""); 
define("mysqli_DB","schooldb"); 

$con=mysqli_connect(mysqli_HOST,mysqli_USER,mysqli_PASSWORD,mysqli_DB) or die("Unable to connection. Check connection parameters"); 

?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
ini_set('display_errors', 0); 

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dbs/dbconnect.php"; 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/functions/functions.php"; 
?> 
<html>
  <div id="bodycontainer"> 
    <?php $insertSQL="INSERT INTO newstudent(col1,col2)values ('data1','data2')"; $result=mysqli_query($con,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error()); mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE newstudent SET status ='A' WHERE studid=$studid"); $parentid=setparentid_new($studid); ------- ------ ------ ?> 
</html>
```

**`setparentid_new()` function:**

```
setparentid_new($studid) { 
   $sql    = "SELECT * FROM parentsmaster WHERE childid=$studid"; 
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error()); 
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

   if($count==1) { 
     $mynewarray = array(); 
     foreach ($mynewarray as $key => $row) { 
       $array_depth[$parentid] = $row['parentid']; 
     } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: 1. dbconnect.php
<?php
    define("mysqli_HOST","localhost");
    define("mysqli_USER","root");
    define("mysqli_PASSWORD","");
    define("mysqli_DB","schooldb");
$con=mysqli_connect(mysqli_HOST,mysqli_USER,mysqli_PASSWORD,mysqli_DB) or die("Unable to connection. Check connection parameters");
?>

Comment: 2. index.php
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dbs/dbconnect.php";
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/functions/functions.php";
    ?>
<html> 
----
  <div id="bodycontainer">
            <?php

  $insertSQL="INSERT INTO newstudent(col1,col2)values ('data1','data2')";

        $result=mysqli_query($con,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error()); 
      mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE newstudent SET status ='A' WHERE studid=$studid"); 
$parentid=setparentid_new($studid);
-------
------
------
?php
</html>

Comment: 3.    function setparentid_new($studid){
    
        $sql="SELECT * FROM parentsmaster WHERE childid=$studid";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count==1){                        
            -----
            -------
            $mynewarray=array();
            foreach ($mynewarray as $key => $row)
            {
                -----
                $array_depth[$parentid] = $row['parentid']; 
            }  
          }          
        }

Comment: I share the shorten code in the first 3 comments. Friends pls help to add db connection string like $con globally to access in all functions. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you put the code in your question, and use the formatting to show it as code.  You can edit your own question and add the information.   You'll get better help if you make the question presentable.

Comment: From a quick glance at the prose in the comments, you are correct that you are not passing $conn to the inside of the function.  To do that, you would do the same as you did with `$studid`:  `function setparentid_new($studid, $conn) { ... }`.  You might be tempted to do something like `function setparentid_new($studid) { global $conn; ... }`, but IMHO that's a path to some bad programming practices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : Make other functions access the $conn variable inside my database connection function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188985/php-make-other-functions-access-the-conn-variable-inside-my-database-connecti)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your structure, but as I understand from your comment, the solution is to define a global variable in index.php and than assign him the db connection.

index.php file:

```
<?php

    $settings = new stdClass;

    require ("db_connection.php");

    require ("functions.php");

    echo "Hello World!";
```

db_connection.php file example, note the `global $settings` call:

```
function db_con($config) {
    global $settings; // This is how you should call the global $settings var inside the functions.

    $settings->db = mysqli_connection...
}
```

Use the same global call in functions.php file's functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in two ways:

1. Declaring in the function.php a variable connection then you can pass it by a getter function

   ```
   --function.php--
   $con;    
   function getCon() {
       global $con;
       return $con;
   }
   --other page--
   include('function.php');
   function a(){
   1.$con=getCon();
   2.global $con
   }
   ```
2. Set the connection in the session scope, that allows you to pass the connection between the pages.

   ```
   set/update
   $_SESSION["con"]=$con;
   get
   $con=$_SESSION["con"]
   ```