# php database instance sharing using inheritance, looking for a short example

Tags: php

I copied this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189317/13865853
I have a `connection.php` where it resides:

```
<?php
class Db
{
    //new version with user authentication
    private static $servername;
    private static $dbname;
    private static $admin_user;
    private static $admin_password;

    private static $init = False;
    public static $conn;

    public static function initialize(){
        //if(self::$init===TRUE)
          //  return;
        $servername = "localhost";
        $admin_user = "blah";
        $admin_password = "blahblah";
        $dbname = "blah";
        self::$init = TRUE;
        self::$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $admin_user, $admin_password, $dbname);
    }
}
//initialize db
Db::initialize();
//check connection
if(!Db::$conn){
    die("Connect failed " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//create table Users
```

I include this in my `model.php`:

```
<?php

//require_once('connection.php');
require_once('connection_tru.php');
$command = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
if(isset($_POST['command'])){
    $command = $_POST['command'];
}
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
$email = '';
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
//Signin
//check is user exists
//for Join this should return false
//for SignIn this should return true
function user_exists($username){
.
.
.
```

But then when I try to include it in a `model2.php` it does not work:

```
<?php
/* model2
author:
*/
//require_once('connection.php');
require('model.php'); //this did not work either

function post_a_question($q, $username){

    $user_id = get_user_id($username);
    //user found proceed to post question in DB
    $current_date = date("Ymd");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Questions(Question, UserId, Date)
                            VALUES('$q', '$user_id', '$current_date')";
    $result = mysqli_query(Db::$conn, $sql);
    if($result!=false){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

I commented up there that I tried `include('model.php`) thinking it would make the `Db::$conn` available in `model2.php` but it did not work.

Right now, I just put all the functions in `model2.php` in the `model.php` file and it works but my school assignment requires that there are separate model files for the functions I have to write.
How do I use this one connection in separate files?

Edit: The answer below says to use inheritance with parent class `ParentModel` that has a method to connect to db which each derived class `ChildModel` and `ChildModel2`can also call but I only want to make one connection so they shouldn't call it.

How would I use inheritance to pass the one and only `$conn` to the derived classes?  I'm not stuck on inheritance so other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Don't use singleton for this. Learn about dependency injection and IoC containers. Use autoloader to load classes. This will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a main Model class which contains the functions of connection class. Then extend model and model2 classes from the main Model.(object-oriented programming)

In this way you can access the functions of parent class.[link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_inheritance.asp)

Comment: This is great. I'm new to PHP but I guess OOP is OOP.

Comment: But the question still is, how to pass that one connection without having derived classes make their own connections.  I heard multiple connections to the same database is bad.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with your answer?